# Pandas: Apply function to each float64 but get unhashable type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame where the columns from index 100:1000 are `float64`.  I'd like to apply a custom function to each cell in these columns.  From googling around, I see I can do something like:

```
def scale(elem):
    ret_val = math.log10(abs(elem)+1)
    if elem >= 0:
        return ret_val
    else:
        return -1 * ret_val

df[:, 100:1000].apply(np.vectorize(scale))
```

But running this gives me:

`TypeError: unhashable type`.  It doesn't specify which though.  If I look at the `dtypes` for these columns:

```
set(df.iloc[:, 100:1000].dtypes)
```

I get:

```
{dtype('float64')}
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong here?  The stacktrace is pretty unhelpful here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a typo which caused the `TypeError`. 
The correct way to call `apply` should be:

```
df.iloc[:, 100:1000].apply(np.vectorize(scale))
# iloc was missing in your code!!
```

It is more efficient (and less error prone) to rewrite your `scale` function into array manner:

```
a = df.values[:, 100:1000]
p = np.ones(a.shape)
p[a<0] = -1
result = np.log10(abs(a)+1)*p
```

### Performance comparison

To compare the runtime, a DataFrame `df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,1000)))` is used below.

[image: timeit_results]